# Multiple defintion of test fixtures in google test

Tags: googletest

I have a set of generic unit tests in a .hpp file that more than one test file must include.

But it gets multiple copies of the same file and the generic .hpp file complaints about multiple definition of the Test fixtures.

Need help on how to approach this.

Comment: Using [`inline`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14517625/6243352) might be an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to separate the gtest class declarations from the definitions in the usual way using .hpp and .cpp files.

So rather than defining the test functions and fixtures in the header, move these to a source file which `#include`s the header. So if e.g. you have `test.hpp` as:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

class MyTest : public ::testing::Test {
 protected:
  void TestFunction(int i) {
    ASSERT_GT(10, i);
  }
};

TEST_F(MyTest, first_test) {
  ASSERT_NE(1, 2);
  TestFunction(9);
}
```

change `test.hpp` to:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

class MyTest : public ::testing::Test {
 protected:
  void TestFunction(int i);
};
```

and add `test.cpp`:

```
#include "test.hpp"

void MyTest::TestFunction(int i) {
  ASSERT_GT(10, i);
}

TEST_F(MyTest, first_test) {
  ASSERT_NE(1, 2);
  TestFunction(9);
}
```

If you're including the same test header in multiple places are you really looking for typed tests or type-parameterised tests?  See http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_AdvancedGuide#Typed_Tests for further details.