# Return Value with Function Prototype

Tags: c++, return-value, function-prototypes

The problem that I am having is that VS (visual studio) gives me error C4715 'functionadd': must return a value. I understand what the compiler is trying to tell me; however, I don't know how to fix it. I am simply trying to get more familiar with function prototyping!!! Lastly, if someone can also show me how to prototype the struct it would also be much appreciated.

Main.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "func.h"



enum class myenum {
    NUMBERONE,
    NUMBERTWO,
    NUMBERTHREE,
    NUMBERFOUR,
    NUMBERFIVE,
};

struct mystruct{
    int age = 9;
    int willbeage;
    int avg;
    std::string about;
    std::string lastname;
} mystruct1;

int main()


{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

func.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef FUNC_H
#define FUNC_H
#include "pch.h"
int functionadd(int, int, int) {
}
void functionadd() {
}

int functionadd(int, int, int, int) {
}
#endif
```

func.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
int functionadd(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a + b + c;
}
void functionadd() {
    std::cout << "Hello";
}

int functionadd(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    return a + b + c + d;
}
```

Comment: Prototypes may not have a body (even not an empty `{ }`). Instead, replace it by a single semicolon (`;`). Have a look at the link provided by @1201ProgramAlarm to see how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a C++ header file include implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14517546/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You header file contains definitions for functions, not function prototypes. Get rid of the `{}` characters and terminate your prototypes with `;`.

```
#pragma once
#ifndef FUNC_H
#define FUNC_H
#include "pch.h"
int functionadd(int, int, int);
void functionadd();
int functionadd(int, int, int, int);
#endif
```

Comment: Oh God, such a simple mistake.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to accept my answer so others won't come stumbling in here to find it already answered.

Comment: Ty for reminding