# Including a specific function in the header file causes and error when trying to include that header file

Tags: c++, function, sdl, inline

This is my `threeD.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include "SDL.h"
#include <vector>

struct vec3
{
    float x, y, z;
};

struct vec2
{
    float x, y;
};

struct triangle3D
{
    vec3 v[3];
};

class Triangle2D
{
    Triangle2D(vec2 v1, vec2 v2, vec2 v3)
    {
        this->v[0] = v1;
        this->v[1] = v2;
        this->v[2] = v3;
    }
    ~Triangle2D() { };

    void draw(SDL_Renderer* renderer, int r, int g, int b, int a)
    {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, r, g, b, a);
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, v[0].x, v[0].y, v[1].x, v[1].y);
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, v[1].x, v[1].y, v[2].x, v[2].y);
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, v[2].x, v[2].y, v[0].x, v[0].y);
    }

private:
    vec2 v[3];
};

vec2 projectAndTransform(SDL_Window* window, vec3 v, float fov)
{
    vec2 newVec;
    float fovScale = fov/ v.z;
    float w = (float)SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->w;
    float h = (float)SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->h;
    newVec.x = (v.x + 1) * (w / 2);
    newVec.y = (v.y + 1) * (h / 2);
    return newVec;
}

struct mesh3D
{
    std::vector<triangle3D> m;
};
 
struct mesh2D
{
    std::vector<Triangle2D> m;
};
```

This is my `game.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include "SDL.h"
#include "threeD.h"

class Game
{
public:

    Game(const char* windowName, unsigned int xWindowPos, unsigned int yWindowPos
        , unsigned int windowWidth, unsigned int windowHeight, bool fullScreen);
    ~Game();

    bool init();
    bool constructWindowAndRenderer
    (
        const char* windowName,
        unsigned int xWindowPos,
        unsigned int yWindowPos,
        unsigned int windowWidth,
        unsigned int windowHeight,
        bool fullScreen = false
    );

    void update();
    SDL_Window* getWindow();
    void clearWindow();
    void render();
    bool handleEvents();

private:
    SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;
    SDL_Event event;
    bool quit = false;

    mesh3D m;

    
};
```

Whenever  I try to include `threeD.h` into game.h I get an error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2005 "struct vec2 __cdecl projectAndTransform(struct SDL_Window *,struct vec3,float)" (? 
projectAndTransform@@YA?AUvec2@@PAUSDL_Window@@Uvec3@@M@Z) already defined in game.obj  learnSDL     
C:\Users\myself\source\repos\learn\learn\main.obj   1
```

From the error message, I figured there is something wrong with `projectAndTransform` function in `threeD.h` file. So I tried commenting it out, and it worked fine. The problem must be `projectAndTransform` function, but I cant see anything in the function that could cause errors. Thanks

Comment: Try marking that function inline

Comment: @puio Oh wow, I don't know how, but it worked. Thanks

Comment: @puio I was just looking online what inline is, and I get what it is now, but I am failing to see how not making the function inline would cause the `#include` statement to fail. Can you please give me the name of this concept(if there is one), or link to any article that explains this. Appreciate it thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline

```
// function included in multiple source files must be inline
inline int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

> There may be more than one definition of an inline function or variable (since C++17) in the program as long as each definition appears in a different translation unit and (for non-static inline functions and variables (since C++17)) all definitions are identical. For example, an inline function or an inline variable (since C++17) may be defined in a header file that is #include'd in multiple source files.

- [How can a C++ header file include implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517546/how-can-a-c-header-file-include-implementation?noredirect=1&lq=1)