# C++ polymorphism, a wrong method is being called

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule

I have a project with a situation where a function of a wrong object is being called.

To simplify it, I created a new CPP project in visual studio.
The project has three files (attached at the bottom) with 2 modules, derived_1 and derived_2 which contain class base_t and override a virtual function of an interface class.

When attempting to call the virtual function of one object I see that it is the function of the other object which is being called.

I also opened the map file and saw that the wrong method is the one being linked.

base.hpp:

```
#ifndef BASE_HPP
#define BASE_HPP

extern int globalFlag;

class base_t {
public:
    struct callBack_t {
        virtual void virtualFunction(void) = 0;
    };
    
    base_t(callBack_t& callBack)
        : _callBack(callBack) {}

    void run() { _callBack.virtualFunction(); }

    callBack_t& _callBack;
};

#endif //BASE_HPP
```

derived_1.cpp:

```
#include "base.hpp"

class derivedCallBack_t : public base_t::callBack_t
{
public:
    void virtualFunction(void) {
        globalFlag = 1;
    }
};

class derived_1_t
{
public:
    derived_1_t(void);
    
    derivedCallBack_t* _derivedCallBack;
    base_t _base;
};

derived_1_t::derived_1_t(void):
    _derivedCallBack(new derivedCallBack_t()),
    _base(base_t(*_derivedCallBack))
{}
```

derived_2.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "base.hpp"

class derivedCallBack_t : public base_t::callBack_t
{
public:
    void virtualFunction(void) {
        globalFlag = 2;
    }
};

class derived_2_t
{
public:
    derived_2_t(void):
        _derivedCallBack(new derivedCallBack_t())
        , _base(base_t(*_derivedCallBack))
    {}

    derivedCallBack_t* _derivedCallBack;
    base_t _base;
};


int globalFlag = 0;
int main()
{
    derived_2_t derived = derived_2_t();
    derived._base.run();
    std::cout << "globalFlag " << globalFlag; //expecting globalFlag to be 2
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two classes with the same name?

Comment: _"When attempting to call the virtual function of one object I see that it is the function of the other object which is being called."_ - You have an [ODR violation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) so don't over-analyze it. Just fix the problem.

Comment: Also make sure you follow these guidelines (with respect to using the "override" keyword). [C++ core guidelines R.128](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c128-virtual-functions-should-specify-exactly-one-of-virtual-override-or-final). If you do that the compiler will help you with better warnings too

Comment: Note that identifiers ending with "_t" are reserved for the implementation in the POSIX standard. There are many other identifiers to choose from.

Answer (score 8):

Your program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required (IFNDR), because `class derivedCallBack_t` is defined in two files in two different ways. This violates the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).
IFNDR means your program isn't valid C++, and executing it is undefined behavior.

It's generally possible to have class definitions in multiple files; see [How can a C++ header file include implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14517546/5740428). However, the definition has to be the same everywhere.

- `derivedCallBack_t` in one file sets `globalFlag = 1`
- `derivedCallBack_t` in another file sets `globalFlag = 2`

What happens in practice is that the linker can assume that if there are multiple definitions, they all have to be exactly the same. It then arbitrarily picks one of the two definitions, and this happened to be the one which sets `globalFlag = 1` in your case.

#### Solution

***EVERYTHING*** that is declared and used *only* in one source file needs to have internal linkage (see [What is external linkage and internal linkage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1358400/5740428)).
Otherwise, there is no way to ensure safety.
Nothing prevents you from having conflicting definitions in multiple files by accident.

```cpp
// derived_1.cpp
namespace {
class derivedCallBack_t : public base_t::callBack_t { /* ... */ };
class derived_1_t { /* ... */ }; // note: you could just call this derived_t
}
```

```cpp
// derived_2.cpp
namespace {
class derivedCallBack_t : public base_t::callBack_t { /* ... */ };
class derived_2_t { /* ... */ };  // note: you could just call this derived_t
}
```

Putting classes in an [unnamed namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces) gives them internal linkage, so the two classes will have the same name, but be entirely distinct.

The same principle applies to `derived_1_t` and `derived_2_t`. Adding a number to the name doesn't prevent you from making the same mistake in a different place.

Comment: So I should either change the name of one of the derivedCallBack_t classes, move there definition into derived_2_t / derived_1_t classes, or make sure each cpp file is it own namespace

Comment: @Hagai adding a number to the name is the worst option. It doesn't really fix the problem and is *kinda* working like a `file_1::` namespace. No matter what, everything needs to be in an unnamed namespace. On top of that, it would be good to have meaningful names for your classes to improve code quality, so that you can distinguish them with more than just a number in the name. If both `derived_t` are doing virtually the same thing, you could just use the same name for both, as long as they are in an unnamed namespace.

Answer (score 4):

Your program is in violation of [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) because there are two incompatible definitions of `derivedCallBack_t::virtualFunction`. The behaviour is undefined.

You have to rename one of the classes named `derivedCallBack_t`, or put the two classes in two different namespaces. I suppose you want two different classes here, each one local to its respective translation unit. In this situation unnamed namespace do the trick:

```
namespace {
   class derivedCallBack_t : public base_t::callBack_t // etc
}
```

Comment: Or OP puts the conflicting definitions (and better also `derived_*_t` to avoid further ODR violation) in unnamed namespaces to give them internal linkage, since it seems OP is using them each in only one translation unit.